# Regex in Python. How to match a string but not in comments?

Tags: python, regex

I want to match any Chinese character in  `""`， but not in the comment of Lua, i.e: after `--`.

For example, in string `Tips("中文") -- "注释"`，`中文` should be matched, but not `注释`.

The regex I write is `ur'(?<!--.*?)"([\u4e00-\u9fff]+)"'`，but Python gives an error: `look-behind requires fixed-width pattern`.

So how to fix this?

Comment: What are you doing, extracting or replacing? It is not actually safe to do with a single regex, see https://ideone.com/YyVjhW. It won't work as expected if you have `local s = "--中文" -- 中文`

Comment: What I want to do is actually find Chinese in quotes and make a replacement.

Comment: Great. 1) Find the quotes, 2) Replace only what you need inside quotes. What is the problem? Please provide an exact test case with sample text and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You could just capture all Chinese characters between quotes, capture any comment start ´--´ indicators, and then throw away all the matches after that indicator.